# Performance benefits of kzalloc() / kmem_cache_zalloc()?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, dynamic-memory-allocation, slab

Apart from clean way to write code, is there any other benefit (specially from performance point of view) to use `kzalloc()` / `kmem_cache_zalloc()` as compare to `kmalloc()` / `kmem_cache_alloc()` + `memset()`?

I tried to measure their performance, but results are almost same.

> Kernel version: 4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64

Below code is creating 2 million slab objects each of 4096 bytes:

```c
#define DATA_NUMBER    2000000
char *data[DATA_NUMBER];

/* kthread */
static int zero_slab(void *arg)
{
        unsigned int            counter, i;
        struct kmem_cache       *mp_cache;
        unsigned long           before, after;

        mp_cache = kmem_cache_create("MP_CACHE", PAGE_SIZE, 0, 0, NULL);
        if (!mp_cache) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "Failed to create slab.\n");
                return -ENOMEM;
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "Slab MP_CACHE is created.\n");

        before = ktime_get();
        for (counter = 0; counter < DATA_NUMBER; counter++) {
                // data[counter] = kmem_cache_zalloc(mp_cache, GFP_KERNEL);
                data[counter] = kmem_cache_alloc(mp_cache, GFP_KERNEL);
                if (!data[counter])
                        goto err_out;
                memset(data[counter], 0, PAGE_SIZE);
        }
        after = ktime_get() - before;
        printk(KERN_INFO "Time taken in ns (%lu)\n", after);

err_out:
        printk(KERN_INFO "Total objects : %u\n", counter);
        for (i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
                kmem_cache_free(mp_cache, data[i]);
        kmem_cache_destroy(mp_cache);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apart from clean way to write code, is there any other benefit

Nope. That's it. `kzalloc` is simply a wrapper around `kmalloc` that passes `__GFP_ZERO`. That flag tells `kmalloc` to do `memset` for you before returning. There is no performance difference between `kmalloc(x, GFP_KERNEL) + memset()` and `kmalloc(x, GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_ZERO)`.

Comment: I would add that if zeroed memory is needed it's better to use **z** variant of allocation to avoid open coding existing APIs.